# In PostgreSQL: Creating a third table by joining columns of two table and new table rows should be updated in realtime

Tags: postgresql

I am having N number of tables(around 100) as shown below. These are base tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    SignalID NCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp VARCHAR(24) NOT  NULL,
    Value DOUBLE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table2 
(
    SignalID NCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    Timestamp VARCHAR(24) NOT  NULL,
    Value DOUBLE NOT NULL
)

table3(), table4(), so on.............
```

Now I have a final table as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE final_table 
(
    Timestamp VARCHAR(24) NOT  NULL,
    table1_Value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    table2_Value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    table3_Value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    table4_Value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    -- so on,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
)
```

Base tables (like table1, table2, table3 and so on) rows will be updated in realtime like 50 rows will be inserted per second. Now what i want is to join all the base tables and make them copied to final_table when timestamp of all the base tables are equal. This should happen in realtime. Whenever a new row is inserted in base tables, final_table should also update with new row.

Is it possible to implement this?

I want a final table(with all value columns from base tables joined and copied to this) because, I want to access that table using python code for processing the values. As there are 50 rows inserted every second, I am planning to use NOTIFY/LISTEN and Trigger method. It will be difficult to handle N number of triggers if I can create a final table.

I have tried using a view (with all the value columns from base table joined and copied to view). But there is issue with view where I can't use `AFTER INSERT ON` trigger on views. This only works on tables.

Or is there any kind of trigger on VIEW where a pg_notify will be sent to client when new row inserted to VIEW?

Comment: "*I want to access that table using python code for processing the values*" - you wouldn't access it any differently than you would access the view that you currently have. Use the view!

Comment: It seems like You're trying to build architecture that will be very hard to maintain and determining the state of Your database will be also very hard. You need to educate more in relational databases, in general, no offence. I think You can skip building the third table and proceed directly to python code - You can prepare a query that gets data from the two tables, joins them properly and does any other transformations You want. But again, it's like creating a view on the fly.

Comment: @Bergi I am not using VIEW because, I am using Notify/Listen method to get data from PSQL database. As view doesn't support AFTER INSERT ON trigger on Rows, thats why I wants to use table.

Comment: @JakubMałecki Yes I can directly read 2 tables using python. But in my scenario I will have N number of tables in realtime. Maybe around 100 tables. Reading 100 tables will consume more time. This is the reason I wanted single table. And I wants to use Listen/Notify concept to read data from database. So I feel it will be difficult to handle N number of triggers .

Comment: @Balaji Please [edit] your question to mention that in the post. But if you want to use triggers anyway, I doubt there is a way you can build that third table without use of triggers, so you may as well send your notifications from the triggers on table1 and table2

Comment: @Balaji Edit the question and add this, it's an important detail. It sounds like you'll need two triggers, one on each table, each checking if the incoming row has a match in the other table and broadcasting it on your channel via `NOTIFY`. Or merge the two tables, adding a differentiator column - instead of each emitter inserting into its own table, make each insert into the same common one, always annotating the row with the identifier of the source. A single table, a single trigger - might be more convenient to maintain if you plan to scale this to collect signals from a 100+ emitters

Comment: @Zegarek I have edited my question. I hope the question is clear.

Comment: @Bergi I have edited my question. I hope the question is clear.

Comment: @Balaji, ater the edits there's a lot more light on the problem now. However, I still doubt if this is the proper way of designing the solution. You mentioned that You may have 100 tables, for each there's a 50 new rows inserted per second. I cannot magine how the final table will be updated? If after new rows appear in any table then it has to be recreated continuousely (?). I guess You're struggling with a broader issue - the general architecture of the system You're trying to build. But maybe I just don't get the problem

Comment: @Balaji also, are you sure your target RDBMS is PostgreSQL? You're using `nchar` that's in Oracle, MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server, among others, but not in PostgreSQL - it only [accepts it as an alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) for [`char`/`bpchar`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html). Did you use the wrong tag, or are you moving from another RDBMS to PostgreSQL?

Comment: @JakubMałecki Yes that is our scenario. Generally I have told we will 100 tables which will updated every second with 50 rows each. Currently We have 10 tables only. I have to to access Value column of each table when ever new row is inserted. I cannot access 10 tables at time. That is the reason I am trying create a final table which will be based on all 10 base tables. So it will be easy for me to access single table instead of 10 tables.

Comment: @Zegarek Yes that table was used in MySQL. Now we are using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another take: you can keep feeding all signals into one, common table and construct your "incremental materialized view" on the fly, in the same singular trigger which broadcasts `notify` to your python code.

```
create table table_all_signals (
    source_id int not null,
    signal_id text not null,
    signal_timestamp timestamp not null,
    value numeric not null );

create table signals_per_source_over_time(
  signal_timestamp timestamp unique );
```

Whenever you get a signal from any source, the trigger checks if it's already collecting signals from that source and if not, adds the new source dynamically. The same trigger relays the incoming information to your python code via `pg_notify()`.

```
create function f_signal_collector()returns trigger as $f$
declare target_value_column text:=concat_ws('_','source',new.source_id,'value');
        new_signals_per_source_over_time record;
begin 
  if not exists (select from information_schema.columns
             where table_schema='public'
             and table_name='signals_per_source_over_time'
             and column_name=target_value_column)
  then
     execute format ($dynamic_sql$
                     alter table public.signals_per_source_over_time 
                     add column %I numeric;
                     $dynamic_sql$, target_value_column);
  end if;
  execute format ($dynamic_sql$
                     insert into public.signals_per_source_over_time AS n
                     (signal_timestamp,%1$I)
                     values ($1,$2)
                     on conflict (signal_timestamp) do update
                     set %1$I=$2
                     returning n.*;
                  $dynamic_sql$, target_value_column)
           using new.signal_timestamp, new.value
           into new_signals_per_source_over_time;
  perform pg_notify('incoming_signals_feed', 
                     to_jsonb(new_signals_per_source_over_time)::text);
  return new;
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t_signal_collector after insert or update on table_all_signals
for each row execute function f_signal_collector();
```

Generating some sample signals:

```
select setseed(0.2);
insert into table_all_signals 
select random()*5,
       gen_random_uuid(),
       '2023-11-21 12:46:49.734534'::timestamp-'100 microseconds'::interval*random(),
       round((random()*1e3)::numeric,6)
from generate_series(1,1e3,1);

select * from table_all_signals order by signal_timestamp,source_id limit 6;
```

| source_id | signal_id | signal_timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | f07e06ad-9416-415c-9678-dd8228a292f5 | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | 796.485640 |
| 1 | 9bbb6f5e-6c5c-4f30-a468-04bcbdad0488 | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | 711.898776 |
| 1 | 308d53f9-5553-4085-b19a-c40bddd1afb8 | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | 621.605431 |
| 1 | ac4ec48f-62d6-40af-8970-636e7bc1858f | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | 350.894326 |
| 2 | 36b964a7-2f76-4bb2-9fd2-e3ecc372cebb | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | 921.574251 |
| 3 | 3f939a24-cde0-42f7-9d0f-c3fca29d4dd2 | 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | 932.034978 |

You can see they automatically populate your other table on the fly, adjusting its structure accordingly.

```
select * from signals_per_source_over_time order by signal_timestamp limit 5;
```

| signal_timestamp | source_5_value | source_4_value | source_3_value | source_0_value | source_1_value | source_2_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734434 | *null* | *null* | 484.759824 | 796.485640 | 621.605431 | 921.574251 |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734435 | *null* | 750.385100 | 833.484142 | 604.862822 | 530.592514 | 674.441018 |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734436 | 324.038718 | 45.646781 | 425.312724 | 127.251620 | 982.819011 | 828.340270 |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734437 | 68.402196 | 990.369557 | *null* | 499.607598 | 672.720661 | *null* |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734438 | *null* | 491.357430 | 406.220658 | *null* | 380.443741 | 455.597406 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9QtJ2iD)

1. The trigger keeps writing and updating your structure.
2. Each change is published via `notify` for your python code to `listen` to.
3. Note that the heavier a table grows, the longer `alter table` gets, so if you don't ever need the full table, you can just keep a view for the purpose of looking up signals that match the new one's timestamp, and feed that into `notify`.
4. You'll get multiple notifications for the same timestamp, whenever a new signal matching an older timestamp arrives. Because of that, it would make more sense to relay just the timestamp, source and value in `notify` and assemble/update your output structure entirely in python.

Answer (score 1):

For storage and access, it's easier, more convenient and efficient if you merge these tables and just save source info in an additional field for each entry. Whenever you want to structure the information the way you showed in your example, you can use `crosstab()` from [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) extension. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/F_wjmL1s)

```sql
create table table_all (
    source_id int not null,
    signal_id text not null,
    signal_timestamp timestamp not null,
    value numeric not null );

create extension tablefunc;

select * from crosstab($s1$ 
  select a.signal_timestamp, b.source_id, round(avg(value),6)
  from (select distinct signal_timestamp from table_all) AS a 
  join (select distinct source_id from table_all) AS b on true
  natural left join table_all
  group by 1,2 order by 1,2
$s1$) AS ct(signal_timestamp timestamp, "source_0_value" numeric, "source_1_value" numeric, "source_2_value" numeric, "source_3_value" numeric, "source_4_value" numeric, "source_5_value" numeric);
```

| signal_timestamp | source_0_value | source_1_value | source_2_value | source_3_value | source_4_value | source_5_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734515 | 435.360227 | 525.596913 | 668.464315 | 663.286502 | 379.664059 | *null* |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734516 | *null* | *null* | 845.618261 | 231.036637 | 449.268347 | 483.163038 |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734517 | 558.158229 | *null* | 377.138522 | 453.009545 | 474.747528 | *null* |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734518 | 699.251527 | 316.118611 | 396.480418 | *null* | 857.458398 | 503.021461 |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.734519 | 830.661170 | 347.182544 | 931.305928 | 509.378886 | 632.748298 | 411.723710 |
| 2023-11-21 12:46:49.73452 | 568.937359 | 451.818054 | 253.002697 | 359.698710 | 733.449772 | *null* |

1. You can densify this using [`date_bin()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) (shown in the [fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/F_wjmL1s)).
2. I'm rounding just for readability, but the `avg()` might be a good idea in case somewhere, sometime you get two signals from the same source, with the same timestamp. You can swap this for any other [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) to process the peer group.
3. If you want to broadcast something from a trigger, you only need a single one, on this one table.
4. Whenever you need to search for something in all signals, here it's a single select from a single source. With multiple tables, you'd have to search everything separately, `union`, etc.
5. In your proposed structure, new sources mean adding additional tables followed by altering all related structures and triggers, each time. Here, you can just start feeding the data into the main table and add the column to the list at the end.
6. By [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html), you can have the cookie and eat it too: everything interfaces with the main table, but you can attach, detach, manipulate and move around its partitions.
7. There are some additional time-focused features in [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/), based on PostgreSQL.

Here's how you can query *one crosstab row*.

```
select * from crosstab($s1$ 
  select a.signal_timestamp, 
         b.source_id, 
         round(avg(value),6)
  from (select '2023-11-21 12:46:49.734436'::timestamp signal_timestamp) AS a 
  join (select distinct source_id from table_all) AS b on true
  natural left join table_all
  group by 1,2 order by 1,2
$s1$) AS ct(signal_timestamp timestamp, "source_0_value" numeric, "source_1_value" numeric, "source_2_value" numeric, "source_3_value" numeric, "source_4_value" numeric, "source_5_value" numeric);
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a trigger for crosstab? Or How can I access the crosstab row from python in realtime?

Comment: If you want a single row, add a `where` condition that selects a specific timestamp inside the crosstab query, and run that query from your python code. It's already real-time, it'll include everything that's currently in the table as of query time, no caching, no sync or refresh necessary.

Comment: By using this method can I access every row without miss? Our device will insert 50 rows per second. Do I need to query the crosstab for every row in a loop? Or does it works like Trigger-Notify-Listen method?

Comment: And I will not know the timestamp, so I can't mention timestamp (as you mentioed in python query -  '2023-11-21 12:46:49.734436'). It won't feasible to query again and again for every new row. That is the reason I thought of using Notify/Listen method. And in the above crosstab query are a and b the table names? And what is the use table_all?

Comment: `a` and `b` are [aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES). `table_all` is supposed to replace your individual per-source `table_1`, `table_2` and so on. The idea is to feed all signals from all sources into a single table (`table_all`), adding source info in a separate field in each row. If you want your Python code to accept a "live feed" of incoming rows, you can set up the trigger on this one table and broadcast a `notify` from that trigger to `listen` and collect these signals python-side, structured however you want.

Comment: But in my senario, how can I replace table_1, table_2 and so on to table_all. And as I mentioned in my question, I will have only 3 columns in my base table i.e. signalID, timestamp and value. I will not have any column named as sourceid. I have one question- will the table_all gets new rows inserted from my remote devices or this table_all rows will be updated from base tables(table1, table_2 and so on).

Comment: You don't need the `source_id` field to be *in* the source. Instead of setting up a source to insert rows into `table_1`, set it up to instead insert them into `table_all`, adding a constant field with value `1`. For the source that would normally feed `table_2`, do the same, but set its constant to `2` and so on. Even if all these tables were already in place and they were all accepting streams of data, it's easy to re-route them and add the field on the fly using the [`rule`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html) system: see this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oITV-bW4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256031/discussion-between-balaji-and-zegarek).